# How do you quote a comic book?

Tags: quotes, comics

How do you quote a comic book strip? I have to state 75 words and I'm not sure if I should re-write the quote as a novel or not.

Comment: In what context are you quoting the comic? In an academic paper? In fiction writing? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE and do feel free to pick a name for yourself (doesn't have to be your real name).  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  It would be helpful if you gave some context here as it will make a difference in the answers.  I edited your tags best I could but they might need to change again depending on how you flesh out the question.  Right now it's too vague.

Comment: Like user Cyn said, you question is a bit too vague. Consider including a picture of the comic strip and be a little more specific about what you're finding hard about the quotation. I.e. what about it is not obvious to you, or poses difficulty, etc.

Comment: What does "re-write the quote as a novel" mean?